# What's included in the collected gold stat?

Tags: diablo-iii

On the Diablo 3 profile screen, there is a stat called collected gold.

What does it include?

- Gold picked up from the ground?
- Gold earned from quests?
- Gold collected from the trade screen?
- Sales to vendors?
- Sales to the auction house?

[image: Collected Gold]

Comment: Deleted my post due to misreading your question, but I believe that the gold collected stat only goes up from physically picking up gold anyway, I'm just not 100% sure (AH and vendor sales definitely don't count, I'm just unsure about quest gold).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I wanted to test this out my selling some items on the auction house and then seeing if the value changed.

- My Gold Collected before using the AH

[image: Pre-AH]

- Selling some fallen teeth on the AH

[image: Send to Stash]

- Gold Collected after using the AH

[image: Post-AH]

As you can see, the amount **does not change from selling items on the auction house**. And yes, I did click "Send to Stash".

Next I will test out selling to vendors. Before selling my chain belt, I have 76238 gold. After selling it, I have 76242 gold, and if selling to vendors increased Gold Collected, my total Gold Collected should be 144,077 + 4 = 144,081.

[image: Before Selling]
[image: After Selling]

Now, I go back to the menu and check to see if the Gold Collected has gone up. It hasn't.

[image: Nothing Changed]

- Conclusion - **Selling to vendors does not affect Gold Collected.**

Finally, I will complete a quest to see if the reward affects Gold Collected. I will be doing the quest **Heart Of Sin - Kill Azmodan**. During this quest, I avoided all of the monsters prior to Azmodan, to avoid getting any gold.

[image: Entering Azmodan]

As you can see here, I'm entering the lair of Azmodan with the same gold as before - 76242. Below is the screenshot of the quest reward.

[image: Quest Reward]

The Quest Reward is 620 Gold, so that should increase my Gold Collected from 144,077 to 144,077 + 620 = 144,697. Unfortunately, I was forced to get a tiny amount of gold when getting Azmodan's Soul since the gold was in the way. However, I did not collect any gold other than at this point. When I see my Gold Collected, it should see be just a little higher than 144,697.

[image: Gold Collected Final]

144,802. Believe me when I say I collected nowhere near 725 gold. So I come to the conclusion that **quest gold does affect gold collected**.

**TL;DR Gold collected on the ground affects it. Gold from vendors does not affect it. Gold from the auction house does not affect it. Gold from quests affects it.**

Comment: It was my pleasure..

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to throw this out to you, Your gold shows 144,077... Then after checking cheevo gold, its 144,802, but you receive 800 from quest, which means it should be 144,877 or more, but its not, so obviously the quest gold did not affect it after all.

Did some reasearch:

"Did Azmo on normal which nets 620 for quest gold"

Started with: 6,157,779 Gold
Ended with: 6,158,266 Gold
Thats a: 487 Gold Difference

In my Inventory I had: 411,095 Gold, After I did quest and all, I had 412,202. Thats a difference of 1,107. Now if you take 1,107 - 620 "Quest gold" = 487, which is the exact increase in my gold.

So the achievement is in-fact **only affected by gold picked up directly from the ground**, ***and nothing else*** :)

Comment: On his screenshot he shows the Azmodan reward is 620, not 800, so his reasoning still stands. Also yours makes good sense as well! :confused:

Answer (score 2):

One thing not tested here was "gold collected" from trade screen (such as if you offer a power leveling service). There HAS TO BE something else other than just picking up. I was just in a room with someone with over 100 million "gold collected." The interesting thing is that they had no high characters, we were in Act 2 NORMAL. Their profile showed they haven't beat A1 Inferno. And on top of all that, every single quest in A2 Normal was giving them achievements. I take it they did some sort of scam, but you'd assume it was along the lines of a previous AH glitch.. yet you've shown here that gold isn't counted. Hmm..